# Modal dialog box with chat like conversation boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have created a Modal dialog box. I need to create a comment box of half of the width of modal dialog box which shows the comments written(read only). The comment box should be created by div tags. I used decreasing the width, used col-xs-6 but i get columns of the whole width of the dialog box. can any one help me ?

Comment: i am using this code <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="display: table-column; align-content: right; border: 1px solid; width: 40%; float: right; resize: both;"> Comment</div>
         </div>

Comment: [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using bootstrap based on your class names provided...

You can add the row/column syntax into the modal itself.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Half width on medium screens
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Other half on medium screens.  (on small its full width)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: to make myself clear, i am looking to create a section of box like asked 5 min ago which is being displayed below my question.

Comment: I told you exactly how to do it. Go to getboostrap.com and review the CSS and getting started sections.